# Heavy scene on EEVEE

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I have a very heavy scene for EEVEE

can deleting unused materials make the scene lighter?
is it necessary to delete from: blender file or deleting in shader editor already gives result?

is there any feature to automatically delete all materials that are not associated with a mesh?

is there anything else I can do to make the scene light for use in EEVEE?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all unused materials that aren't on any objects, you can do so by following the image below. Just under File -> Clean Up -> Unused Data-Blocks.

[image]

You can also manually delete any materials you don't need by going into the object viewer window, and changing it to file view mode. Go down to materials, select the ones you don't need and delete.

[image]